# Delphi 10 Seatle erro ao compilar RxLib

Tags: delphi, delphi-seatle

Ambiente:
 
Windows 10, Delphi Seatle 10
 
RxLibrary (http://www.micrel.cz/RxLib/dfiles.htm)

Estou tentando compilar um sistema originalmente desenvolvido em D7, no Delphi Seatle e estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
Unit RxDateUtil was compiled with a different version of myapp.RxStrUtils.MakeStr
```

RxDateUtil e RxStrUtils são units (.pas) da lib [RxLibrary] (http://www.micrel.cz/RxLib/dfiles.htm), parece que, no processo de compilação, o Seatle gera um dcu com o nome da aplicação seguida do nome de units da lib, nesse caso "myapp.RxStrUtils.MakeStr", procurando na RxLibrary eu encontro RxUtils, mas não encontro nem RxStrUtils.MakeStr e nem somente MakeStr.

Esse erro ocorre na unit RxFileUtil, na linha:

```
uses{$IFNDEF VER80}{$IFDEF RX_D3}ActiveX, ComObj, ShlObj, {$ELSE}Ole2,
  OleAuto, {$ENDIF}{$ENDIF}RxDateUtil, ...
```

Procurando pelo erro na rede, encontrei [esse link](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/cm_version_conflict_xml.html), que diz mais ou menos o seguinte:

> F2051: Unit %s was compiled with a different version of %s.%s (Delphi)
>  
>   Esse erro ocorre quando uma declaração de simbolo em uma interface é alterada e o compilador não consegue recompilar a unit referenciada nessa declaração pq o fonte não está disponível.

Mas vejam que, no meu caso, a 'unit2' nem existe.

Outra possível causa apontada pelo texto é que o projeto possa ter uma unit com o mesmo nome de uma unit do Delphi, ai teria que renomear a unit2, e alterar as referencias a ela, no meu caso seria myapp.RxStrUtils.MakeStr, mas como fazer isso se essa unit nem existe? ou teria que fazer isso com RxStrUtils? mas existe uma unit no Delphi Seatle com esse nome?

Alguem usa essa lib com o Delphi Seatle? Alguma dica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver isso assim. Retirei todas as referencias(*Componentes e Uses*) do `RXLib` antigo e coloquei os componentes da versão nova do `RXLib` e compilei tudo e funcionou.

Comment: realmente funciona o mau é que da trabalho...